# Problem returning smallint from IBM Db2 dll

Tags: .net, db2, .net-7.0

I'm currently using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore Verson 7.0.0.200.

I select a set of records from a database.

The table has primary key and 2 other alternate keys. The column I'm having an issue with (SEQ_CD) is one of the alternate keys. It is a smallint(2), does not allow nulls and doesn't have a default value.

My consuming api is .Net 7.

This my context

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>(e =>
            {
                e.ToTable("Table", "Schema");
                e.HasKey(k => k.Cd);
                e.HasAlternateKey(k => k.Dc);
                e.HasAlternateKey(k => k.SeqCd);

                e.Property(p => p.CD).HasColumnName("CD");
                e.Property(p => p.DT).HasColumnName("DT");
                e.Property(p => p.SEQ_CD).HasColumnName("SEQ_CD").HasColumnType("smallint(2)");
                e.Property(p => p.CD_DS).HasColumnName("CD_DS");

            });
```

And my class is setup as such:

```
namespace Project.Data.Db2.Models
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public string Cd { get; set; }
        public DateTime fDt { get; set; }
        public short SeqCd { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(TrimmedWhitespaceStringConverter))] //Used to trim the extra whitespace from the db2 character fields.
        public string CD_DS{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Based on previous experience I think this is an issue with converting types from Db2 to .Net. I've check the datatype conversion chart and I've tried Int16. I've also tried short as that is the type that is being used from out other app we are updating with our new project.

No matter what value I save, when I retrieve the value it comes back as 1 for the SEQ_CD. I have verified that the correct values are in the database. Additionally I've setup my api to dump out the generated linq and I've used linqpad to generate sql from linq. Both queries return the correct value when ran directly against the database and that returns the expected result set. Is there something I need to add to my context or to my class?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to generate a context using the IBM.EntityFrameworkCore provider. Once I did this I was able to comment out sections sections until I broke it and then added sections to my existing one until it worked.

I learned my problem was the alternate key setup.

Instead of using `.HasAlternateKey` it has to be done as such:

```
e.HasKey(k => new { k.Cd, k.Dt, k.SeqCd });
```

Once I did this, it returned the correct values from my api.